# Engine overheating and radiator releasing water. What is the issue?

Tags: engine, toyota, radiator, prius

Model: Toyota Prius 2010.

The engine is overheating and the radiator is releasing water, and idea why this is?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you look where the water is coming from?

Comment: A picture of the leak could help in a major way.

Answer (score 1):

The radiator is broken due to a material failure and needs to be replaced.